# Easiest way to populate empty list of Guids with random values

Tags: c#, linq

```
var ids = new List<Guid>(count);
```

I have a multiple items empty list and I am looking for an elegant way to fill it with random Guids, without using for loop, preferably one-liner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inefficient but one line:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(_ => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
```

Much more efficient:

```
var list = new List<Guid>(count);
for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) list.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
```

If the list *already exists*, then... just use the second version. You *can* probably force LINQ to do it without using a loop in your code, but: don't do that. You are looping here, so ... use a loop! Moving the loop into LINQ doesn't improve things - it just makes it harder to read and less efficient to execute.

Comment: Can you add more details for the difference between two?

Comment: I like the first option without calling ```ToList()``` because it will always produce a new list of guids.  You can always call ```ToList()``` on the calling end to keep those references.

Comment: @kamalpreet  I don't believe there's a big difference in the two.  They do the same thing for the most part.

Comment: @kamalpreet multiple iterators are constructed and executed; a delegate is constructed (although in this case it will be cached and reused as a static), and invoked multiple times; the list won't be right-sized, so it'll use multiple arrays as it grows (for large `count`, at least)

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII in terms of what the result is : yes; in terms of what they do to get there: see comment above

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree and for this simpler wins (IMO).  Having both makes the answer stronger and that's appreciated.

Comment: @Fabjan sure, but I don't think that achieves anything useful - heck, just `var list = DoTheThing(count);` *also* hides the loop, yet could be implemented via any mechanism

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is more to your taste, even if its not exactly what you asked for?

```
    static IEnumerable<Guid> RandomGuids()
    {
        while (true) { yield return Guid.NewGuid(); }
    }
```

Comment: This is almost great except it's an endless enumeration.

Comment: You can limit size at the calling site.   `RandomGuids().Take(count)`

Comment: You can; but in general just calling the enumeration will go forever.  I don't think that behavior would be ideal in this situation.

Comment: @LeoBartkus it's pretty elegant solution thank you, I more into that one-liner Marc suggested though

Comment: @BanksySan Oh I see what you mean:  while (!count.Equals(0)) { yield return Guid.NewGuid(); count--; }

Comment: @AndreiKarcheuski … or a for-loop.